# Access denied for user ''@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Tags: laravel

I am trying to establish a mySQL database connection in my Laravel Project. It was working fine but suddenly I can't establish the connection, and get this error.

SQLSTATE[HY000] [1044] Access denied for user ''@'localhost' to database 'database'

I noticed that the username is empty.

the root user has ALL PRIVILEGES granted

User name   Host name   Password    Global privileges   User group  Grant
root          127.0.0.1      No            ALL PRIVILEGES                      Yes

this is my .env part

```
   ` DB_CONNECTION=mysql
     DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
     DB_PORT=3306
     DB_DATABASE=database
     DB_USERNAME=root
     DB_PASSWORD=`
```

and this is the database.php config part

```
      ` 'mysql' => [
        'driver' => 'mysql',
        'url' => env('DATABASE_URL'),
        'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
        'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
        'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
        'name' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
        'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
        'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
        'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
        'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
        'prefix' => '',
        'prefix_indexes' => true,
        'strict' => true,
        'engine' => null,
        'options' => extension_loaded('pdo_mysql') ? array_filter([
            PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA => env('MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA'),
        ]) : [],
    ],`
```

- When I run this command through my terminal mysql -u root -p -h 127.0.0.1 -P 3306 database and when I am prompted to enter a password I just hit enter, the connection get established.

-Tried php artisan config:clear

-Tried restarting the servers multiple times

so where might the problem be?

Comment: Then you are not passing the right user name to the connection.

Comment: isn't the root user has all privileges to all database created on the localhost? I have always used it with no password.

Comment: That may be so, but the connection is not made in the root user's name.

Comment: well how can I change the connection to be made on this username

Comment: I don't know laravel well enough to comment on that one. I personally would take a look at if laravel is using the .env file that has the right connection parameters.